# How to gracefully delete a file from disk in a web application?

Tags: java, spring, temporary-files

In our web application based on some logic we generate a file on disk. Then user's browser can request the file. This will be done by using ajax. I want to delete the file when there is no need for it. What I have done so far is to delete in the following situations:

1. successful completion of the logic when the file sent back to the user
2. if there is any failures before delivery (in case of exceptions I'm deleting the file. Also I've overridden finalize method so in case of garbage collection it is going to be deleted as well).
3. If user's session terminates. Using a listener which listens for `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent`. This cover a scenario in which user request a file then before delivery they close the browser.

Some info about my application: application based on Spring and using singleton-scoped bean injected with a proxy (aop scoped-proxy) to handle file locations in session.

Now, here is the question: If user opens two tabs in a browser and in one of the tabs request the file (assume its a long running process) and in the second tab, log out of the system. In this case the file will be generated and there is no means to be deleted by the system automatically. How can I cover this scenario?

Comment: Make session ID (part of) the file name. For clean up, find and delete all the files for which there is no active sessions.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Calling File.deleteOnExit() in a web application causes a memory leak because the list of files is not cleared until the JVM exits.

Comment: Write a cronjob that will clean up all files older than X days. Run it daily.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Creating a job to clear things up is one solution. Associating the sessionID to files is also good idea. What I decided to do was to use **CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor** and annotate a method in our session scoped bean with **@PreDestroy**. By doing this I could delete the file after user's session scoped bean was terminating. There is one caveat and that is if the file was generated and before delivery server process is killed by any means then this solution is not deleteing the file.